# Listview with Textbox WIndows10

Tags: c#, binding, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have one big problem.

My Mainpage is a shell with splitview and a framelement to load other pages.

I added differnet pages
1. Page is Empty
2. Page contains a listview with different items (from ObservableCollection). If the ItemTemplate contains a TextBox the Apps crashes when I switch between pages a couple of times. I don't know how to handle that? Memory consumption increases every 2-3 times I navigate to the page #2

XAML:

Code behind:

```
    public Day()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.lv_schultag.ItemsSource = (App.Current as App).schuljahr.actual_day[0].stunden;
    }
```

The Debugger stops here in App.g.i.cs:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    };
#endif
```

The unhandled exception `e` is:

```
Für diesen Vorgang ist nicht genügend Speicher verfügbar.
```

In English:

```
System.Exception System.OutOfMemoryException.
```

The MemoryUsage is about 65MB...

Do you have any idea why that happens

Comment: What is the exception (look at the `e` variable) in the App.g.i.cs page?

Comment: @chue x: Thanks for pointing that out: It's {"Für diesen Vorgang ist nicht genügend Speicher verfügbar."} -> System.Exception {System.OutOfMemoryException. But why is it? MemoryUsage is about 65MB...

Comment: sorry, no idea. I cannot tell based on the information presented.

Comment: Is this windows store/universal app/wpf/silverlight? You should add one of those tags.

Comment: Sorry. It's for Windows10 UWP (Windows Store)... maybe it has to do with Windows10?! Or VisualStudio 2015 RC? I know it's quite hard to find the error... but you're the pros ;)

Comment: I've tested it with the Microsoft samplecode (xBindSampleCS) for Windows10 UWP-App: same error here. AFter switching back and forth a while the app crashes with mentioned error (OutOfMemoryExecption). I hope there will be some fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your visual studio and UWP Development tools, Things are working fine now. I was facing similar issues with mapcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest update and SDK there isn't any Problem anymore... just to let you know